# PCI check failing

Tags: pci-dss

I have had a customer come to me with a failed PCI compliance check with the failure apparently caused by an extension I develop.  The scenario is that web page content is served by the extension but a particular string is replaced in the pages HTML server side with the contents of a cookie.  This is flagging a security issue on the compliance check even though the cookie contents is being passed through the PHP function `htmlspecialchars()`.  With the cookie removed completely the check passes.  The strange thing is the same check passes on another website using exactly the same extension but with the cookie present.

What have I missed?

EDIT: To give a bit more detail as per the request in the comment, the value is output in HTML, and the exact failure as shown in the report is as follows:

```
Affected URL:
http://www.somestore.com/somepage.html Affected Variable: cookie_name Injected
text:
PmTmLZjuQsTQRb1U;SecurityMetrics_xss_in_element_event=88bdc4bc6f8451350
a8dbc5753b48066661972c446c248ef44c94800554c44cd// Variation ID:
%3Cbutton%20type=%22button%22%20title=%22Add%20to%20Basket%22%20
class=%22button%20btnCVSS
10.00
FAIL
Port
80
Protocol
TCP
Service
http
Title
Cross-Site Scripting in event tag of HTML element
cart%22%20onclick=%22setLocation('http://www.somestore.com/checkout/cart/add/ue
nc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lY3V2YS5jb20vZGFpbHktbGl2aW5nLmh0bWw_bW9kZT1saX
N0JTIzJTVFJTI4JTI0JTIxJTQwJTI0JTI5JTI4JTI4JTI5JTI5JTI5JTJBJTJBJTJBJTJBJTJBJTJB/pro
duct/2577/form_key/PmTmLZjuQsTQRb1U;SecurityMetrics_xss_in_element_event=
88bdc4bc6f8451350a8dbc5753b48066661972c446c248ef44c94800554c44cd///')
%22%3E%3Cspan%3E%3Cspan%3EAdd%20to%20Basket%3C/span%3E%3C/span
%3E%3C/button%3E
```

Comment: Some more details are needed. Where is the value output, in HTML or JavaScript? What's the exact reason for failure?

Comment: This is interesting, out of curiosity is the sites that passes SSL?

Comment: The SSl certificate is up to date and there are no insecure assets on the page when accessed securely.

Comment: I'm guessing this is not an easy one to shed any light on?

Comment: Do you apply the html encoding before setting the cookie or do you apply it when you include the cookie in the html? The former is an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: I'd say they probably used an automated tool, the tool gave them a readout saying that it worked and the firm didn't follow up to check if it was a false positive and just passed it along to the client saying they failed inspection. I'm more curious how they got by without being HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

You customer is probably trying to qualify for PCI's SAQ A certification, but your extension would require them to use SAQ A-EP.  See the guideline document [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_InstrGuidelines_v3-1.pdf).

Specifically the 5th requirement for A-EP:

> Each element of the payment page(s) delivered to the consumer’s browser originates from either 
>   the merchant’s website or a PCI DSS compliant service provider(s)

This is in contrast to what's required for SAQ A, which requires that **everything** be outsourced.

[This page](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/saq-a-vs-a-ep-what-e-commerce-merchants-service-providers-need-to-know-now/) goes into some more detail about what this difference means (emphasis mine):

> SAQ A:
>
> - Merchant website is **entirely hosted and managed** by a PCI-compliant, third-party payment processor, OR
> - Merchant website provides an iframe or URL that redirects a consumer to a PCI-compliant, third-party payment processor, where **no
>     elements of the page originate from the merchant website**.
>
> SAQ A-EP:
>
> - Merchant website creates a payment form and “direct posts” payment data to PCI-compliant, third-party payment processor, OR
> - Merchant website provides an iframe or URL that redirects a consumer to a PCI-compliant, third-party payment processor, **BUT some
>     elements of the payment page originate from the merchant website.**
>     (Elements would be JavaScript, CSS or any functionality that supports
>     how the payment page is created.)

Your other customer is probably already under A-EP, so your extension doesn't pose a problem for them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Hmmm, still not clear on why the logic the extension is running is causing an issue though.  The error is on a Magento store, and the payment options for Magento either take you off the site completely, i.e. to paypal, or process the payment on the stores checkout in which case there are countless elements on the page from the merchants website.  The error appears specifically related to the fact that the cookie contents is used as the basis for replacing content on the page, presumably assuming malicious code could be added to the cookie, but the contents is escaped?

Comment: Heard back from the customer, he says they are applying for level D version 3.0.

Comment: @JonathanHussey - Hmm.  I've taken another look, and I have another guess.   Try manually setting your cookie's value to `');alert('Hacked you!`  Level D shouldn't have any issues with injected content, but since your cookie is being injected into a **javascript** block, that's very different.

Comment: Would not `htmlspecialchars()` mitigate such an attack, so it would become `&#039;);alert(&#039;Hacked you!`?  I'll give it a go though.

Comment: @JonathanHussey - Depends if [**ENT_QUOTES**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is set, which is not the default.  But even if it is, that means that the attacker just broke your page (even if they don't benefit from it)

Comment: In this case `ENT_QUOTES` is set yes.  They might break the page, but only for themselves  :)  I'm actually looking at different solutions for this, some other data is stored in a file elsewhere so while read/write from disk isn't ideal it would allow the removal of the cookie.  Still don't really see why it's flagged as problematic by the check, but I'm certainly not a compliance expert!

Comment: @JonathanHussey - Neither am I - I've just had to deal with it in the past.  Really, at this point, you should see if your client can get you a better explanation from their [QSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualified_Security_Assessor) and/or put you in touch with them directly.  I *believe* it's possible to get certain automated failures waived with appropriate human analysis.  And even if not, you should be able to get a better understanding of where the problems are. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Yes that's a good call actually - I'll see if I can get in touch directly and find more specifics on why the fail is in fact a fail.